# Class that make asynchronous http requests

Tags: javascript, ajax

I made this function to act sort of like jQuery's `$.ajax`. I intend to use it in small projects where I do not use jQuery (I don't want to load a whole framework just to facilitate http requests).

**Edit: New script incorporating Bob Lauer's suggestions**

```
"use strict";

function OM(obj){
    return new ObjectManipulator(obj);
}
function ObjectManipulator(obj){
    this[0] = obj;
}
ObjectManipulator.prototype.populate = function(newObject){
    for(var i in newObject){
        if(!this[0].hasOwnProperty(i)){
            this[0][i] = newObject[i];
        }
    };
    return this;
}

function ajax(settings){
    return new AjaxRequest(settings);
}
function AjaxRequest(settings){
    settings = OM(settings).populate({
        url:    '/',
        method: 'get',
        type:   'text',
        async:  true,
        data: null
    })[0];

    var done, progress, fail, always;

    var method = settings.method.toUpperCase();
    if(['GET', 'POST', 'PUT', 'DELETE'].indexOf(method) === -1){
        console.log(method + " is not a supported method");
        return;
    }

    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();

    var data = null;
    if(settings.data){
        if(typeof settings.data === 'object'){
            data = new FormData();
            for(prop in settings.data){
                if(settings.data.hasOwnProperty(prop)){
                    data.append(prop, settings.data[prop]);
                }
            }
        }else{
            data = settings.data;
        }
    }

    request.addEventListener('readystatechange', readystatechangeHandler);
    request.addEventListener('progress', progressHandler);

    request.open(method, settings.url, settings.async);
    request.send(data);

    function readystatechangeHandler(){
        if(request.status >= 400){
            if(typeof fail === 'function')   fail(request);
            if(typeof always === 'function') always(request);

            if(typeof fail !== 'function' && typeof always !== 'function'){
                console.error("Error: ", request.status, request.statusText);
                console.error(request);
            }
            request.removeEventListener('readystatechange', readystatechangeHandler);
        }

        if(request.readyState == 4 && request.status == 200){
            if(typeof done === 'function' || typeof always === 'function'){
                var data = request.response;
                if(settings.type.match(/json/gi) || request.responseURL.split(/\./g).pop() == 'json'){
                    data = JSON.parse(request.response);
                }
                if(typeof done == 'function')   done(data);
                if(typeof always == 'function') always(data);
            }
        }
    }
    function progressHandler(event){
        if(!event.lengthComputable) return;
        if(typeof progress == 'function') progress(event);
    }
    this.done     = function(fn){
        done = fn;
        return this;
    }
    this.progress = function(fn){
        progress = fn;
        return this;
    }
    this.fail     = function(fn){
        fail = fn;
        return this;
    }
    this.always   = function(fn){
        always = fn;
        return this;
    }
}
```

**Old script**

```
"use strict";

Object.prototype.populate = function(obj) {
    for(var i in this){
        if(this.hasOwnProperty(i)){
            obj[i] = this[i];
        }
    }
    return obj;
};

function ajax(settings){
    return new ajaxFac(settings);
}
function ajaxFac(settings){
    settings = settings.populate({
        url:    '/',
        method: 'get',
        type:   'text',
        async:  true,
        data: null
    });

    var done, progress, fail, always;

    var method = settings.method.toUpperCase();
    if(['GET', 'POST', 'PUT', 'DELETE'].indexOf(method) == -1){
        console.log(method + " is not a supported method");
        return;
    }

    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();

    var data = null;
    if(settings.data){
        if(typeof settings.data == 'object'){
            data = new FormData();
            for(prop in settings.data){
                if(settings.data.hasOwnProperty(prop)){
                    data.append(prop, settings.data[prop]);
                }
            }
        }else{
            data = settings.data;
        }
    }

    request.addEventListener('readystatechange', readystatechangeHandler);
    request.addEventListener('progress', progressHandler);

    request.open(method, settings.url, settings.async);
    request.send(data);

    function readystatechangeHandler(){
        if(request.status >= 400){
            if(typeof fail == 'function')   fail(request);
            if(typeof always == 'function') always(request);

            if(typeof fail !== 'function' && typeof always !== 'function'){
                console.error("Error: ", request.status, request.statusText);
                console.error(request);
            }
            request.removeEventListener('readystatechange', readystatechangeHandler);
        }

        if(request.readyState == 4 && request.status == 200){
            if(typeof done == 'function' || typeof always == 'function'){
                var data = request.response;
                if(settings.type.match(/json/gi) || request.responseURL.split(/\./g).pop() == 'json'){
                    data = JSON.parse(request.response);
                }
                if(typeof done == 'function')   done(data);
                if(typeof always == 'function') always(data);
            }
        }
    }
    function progressHandler(event){
        if(!event.lengthComputable) return;
        if(typeof progress == 'function') progress(event);
    }

    this.done = function(fn){
        done = fn;
        return this;
    }
    this.progress = function(fn){
        progress = fn;
        return this;
    }
    this.fail = function(fn){
        fail = fn;
        return this;
    }
    this.always = function(fn){
        always = fn;
        return this;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Don't extend `Object.prototype`.  Just create a utility function that takes in 2 objects, and copy the values from one to the other.
- Use `===`, instead of `==`
- `ajaxFac` is not a factory, but a class.  Your `ajax` method is the factory, since its job is to create a `new ajaxFac` every time.  As such, you should rename `ajaxFac` to something more appropriate, and start its name with a capital letter, to denote that it's instantiated using the `new` keyword.
- instead of defining `this.done`, `this.progress`, etc. inside the `ajaxFunc` constructor, define them as `ajaxFunc.prototype.done`, etc.  How you have it set up now, every time you create a new `ajaxFunc`, a new `done`, `progress`, etc. method is created, which takes up memory.  If you move those methods to `ajaxFunc.prototype`, they'll behave exactly the same, but only one method will be created and then shared among all of your `ajaxFunc` instances.  You'll have to structure them slightly different, because `var done, progress, fail, always;` will no longer be in scope, but you can just as easily do something like `this.doneFn = fn; return this;`

Edit:

For prototype usage, it should look something like this:

```
AjaxRequest.prototype.fail = function(fn) {
  this.failFn = fn;
  return this;
};
```

The tricky part is that inside of your `readystatechangeHandler` method, `this` won't refer to your instance of `AjaxRequest`, because it's an anonymous function.  So you'll want to save a reference to `this` in another variable outside of `readystatechangeHandler`, and then you can use that.  Ex:

```
var self = this;
function readystatechangeHandler(){
    if(request.status >= 400){
        if(typeof fail === 'function')   self.failFn(request);
        ...
```

Comment: Thanks for this. These are excellent suggestions. I cringed when I wrote Object.prototype. The only reason I did was because I am planning on making a class to manipulate objects. I have started it with only the populate method.

Comment: I was not able to get the prototyping working for done, progress, etc. Can you give an example for one please?

Comment: I edited my original comment to expand on using prototyping.